# PySpark save DataFrame to actual JSON file

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

How can I save a PySpark DataFrame to a real JSON file?

Following documentation, I have tried

```
df.write.json('myfile.json')
```

It works, but it saves the file as a series of dictionaries, one per line and this does not get read properly by a

```
import json
d = json.load(open('myfile.json'))
```

I would like the file to contain a list of dictionaries. Is there a way?

Comment: have you tried `json.dumps(df.__dict__)`?

Comment: @TalesPádua  `df` is just an interface to a distributed data structure. Its `__dict__` doesn't contain anything useful here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It there a way to do it? Not really, or at least not in an elegant way. You could convert data to Python RDD, compute partition statistics, and build complete document manually but it looks like a waste of time.

If you want to get a `list` of `dicts` just parse files(-s) line by line:

```
with open('myfile.json') as fr:
    dicts = [json.loads(line) for line in fr]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do also something like

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import get_json_object
df=sc.textFile("path/to/file").toDF(["col"])
df.select(get.json.object("col", "$").alias("list_of_dictionaries"))
df.list_of_dictionaries
```

It returns a column object that you could transform into python list